# Update Record in MonogoDB using Node-Red

Tags: mongodb, node-red

I'm new in Node-Red and MongoDB.

I need to update a document in collection using Node-Red.

Here is my code in Function node:

```
var newMsg = msg;
newMsg.operation  = 'findAndModify';
newMsg.payload    = {
                      query: { "UserKey": "mykey" }, 
                      update: { $set: {"Locked": false } }
                    };
return newMsg;
```

But got the below error

"Monog Error: need remove or update".

Edit:

Although the below code is working fine in Mongo shell.

```
db.Users.findAndModify({
                        query: { "UserKey": "mykey" },
                        update: { $set: { "Locked": false } }
                       })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findAndModify` is not one of the supported methods for the mongo node, you will have to do it as a 2 stage process.

Use **Mongo In** node to do a `find`, then update the payload and feed it into a **Mongo Out** node to do a `store`

Comment: i was using mongodb2 node.
But it is worked now .. 
Thank you very much

Comment: @hardilib -  didn't understant this can you explain with an example

Answer (score 0):

@phani-indra, for example, if you have a collection of users with document:

```
{ "chatid" : 324323,
  "alert" : false, 
  "accesslevel" : 4, 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5d76b33c6ff21e0155d035a0") 
}
```

and you want to change key "alert" to true, so your function node in NodeRED will looks something like:

```
var newMsg = { 
  'collection': 'users', 
  'operation': 'update',
  'query': {
    chatid : 324323
  },
  'payload': { 
      $set: {
          alert : false
      }
   } 
}; 
return newMsg;
```

Then feed function node into a **Mongo Out** node.